# Two Range Sliders that adjust one another

Tags: javascript

I am looking to find a way, using javascript to modify the value one one range slider based on the value of another.

I will not be using one slider with two values, but two distinct sliders, stacked one of the other. Each range slider will have a possible value from 1-10. We will call them Slider-A and Slider-B.

For any given value of one of the sliders there will be a specific value the other must be at. I want to allow the user to freely adjust either slider but by doing so the other slider will be adjusted to its matching position.  Here is how the values will relate, the first value represents Slider-A, the second Slider-B.

```
1,  10
2,  9
3,  8
4,  7
5,  6
6,  5
7,  4
8,  3
9,  2
10, 1
```

I'm just not sure where to start any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Start with `range1.addEventListener("input", evt => updateTheOtherOne(evt))`, and then make sure you don't write yourself into an infinite update loop where input1's update changes input2, which changes input1, which changes input2, which [...]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can sometimes be daunting when you're not sure where to start, but posting some attempted code no matter how wrong is always encouraged. The comment should get you started, but I'll provide a full example below to help you out.

```html
<input id="a" type="range" min="1" max="10" value="1">
<input id="b" type="range" min="1" max="10" value="10">

<script>
  // change b when a is adjusted
  document.getElementById('a').addEventListener('change', function (e) {
    document.getElementById('b').value = 10 - (e.target.value - 1)
  })

  // change a when b is adjusted
  document.getElementById('b').addEventListener('change', function (e) {
    document.getElementById('a').value = 10 - (e.target.value - 1)
  })
</script>
```